# Telerik MVC Grid - Group by Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm trying to use Telerik MVC Grid for an application which requires lots of filtering and grouping... On every model I have, it has a property DateTime for storing CreationDate. Sometimes when showing the grid to the user, time isn't important. Also, I had to use ViewModels to avoid circular references since I'm using LINQ.

The problem comes when resorting or grouping results by date. If I use the CreationDate field as a Datetime on my ViewModel and then give it Format on the View to show only date, it sorts fine, works fine, but when grouping it groups using the whole datetime value, so there wont never be anything groupedby. If I use the CreationDate as a string in the ViewModel, it shows fine the first time but will give error if resorting or grouping by date.

Here's the code I have for this case:

VIEWMODEL:

```
    public class CenterViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string Phone{ get; set; }
        public string CreationDate { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult AjaxIndex()
    {
          var model = repository.GetAllRecords()
                    .Select(o => new CenterViewModel
                    {
                        Id = o.Id,
                        Name = o.Name,
                        CityName= o.City.Name,
                        Phone = o.Phone,
                        CreationDate = o.CreationDate .ToShortDateString(),
                        Active = o.Active
                    });

        return View(new GridModel
        {
            Data = model
        });
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

VIEW:

```
   @model IEnumerable<CenterViewModel>

   @(Html.Telerik().Grid<CenterViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(keys =>
    {
        keys.Add(p => p.Id);
    })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Name);
        columns.Bound(o => o.CityName);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Phone);            
        columns.Bound(o => o.CreationDate).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Active).Width(100)
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => {
                    dataBinding.Ajax().Select("AjaxIndex", "Centers", null);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable())
```

The above code would work only for the first load of data, when you resort or group by date it will throw the following exception: "Method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' has no supported translation to SQL." which makes sense, but, I think my intention is pretty clear now.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance,

Comment: That is strange. In my current project I'm using the identical code. binding with `columns.Bound(o => o.Created).Width(100);` and model `Created = dto.Created.ToShortDateString(),`. I can sort, group and everything else. Are you using an ORM and returning the physycal entities in the GetAllRecords? If so that would be the only difference with us. I'm returning an IEnumerable of DTOs which have been mapped from the entities before we assign them to the view model. Maybe it is related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is in your model to use a date that removes the time element. Then in the view, format the date.

VIEWMODEL:

```
public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
var model = repository.GetAllRecords()
                .Select(o => new CenterViewModel
                {
                    Id = o.Id,
                    Name = o.Name,
                    CityName= o.City.Name,
                    Phone = o.Phone,
                    CreationDate = new DateTime(o.CreationDate.Year, o.CreationDate.Month, o.CreationDate.Day),
                    Active = o.Active
                });
```

VIEW:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.CreationDate).Width(200).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
```

Comment: `CreationDate` is a `string` in the `CenterViewModel` not a `DateTime` object. You are missing the `.ToString()` in the end. With a `string` I also wasn't able to get the `.Format("{...}")` to make any difference in the format the value shows up. But that could be just me and might work very well for `met.lord`.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl CreationDate in the model has a .ToShortDateString() at the end, which suggests to me that it is a DateTime object not a string. I am suggesting that op keep it a DateTime instead of converting it to a string. In the view, the .Format I suggested will only work with a DateTime.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I changed my answer so that the ViewModel has CreationDate as a DateTime.

Comment: `@Daniel` Probably a good idea to make it a `DateTime`. That might also make the whole .Format work. I will also try that on my own project in work. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This actually is a good idea and it works because when you set a new DateTime object it's setting the same time (12am) value for each element.Then, it's grouped properly. Thanks!